# calculate the entropy of 2d points

Tags: statistics, entropy

If I understand it correctly, one can use
$$
-\sum_i^N x_i \ln (x_i)
$$
to estimate the entropy a set of values $x_i$. Does the domain matter? Is $x_i \in (0,1)$ the default domain? Anyway, why the above formula can measure the entropy? the wikipedia does not explain.

In physics, the entropy of particles in a box (or a rectangle) is not difficult to conceive. However, how to calcute the entropy of a set of 2d points $\mathbf{x}_i \in (0,1)^2 $ ?

Comment: The log of 0 is not defined, so you need values >0.

Comment: thank you! Can I assume $x\in (0,1)$ for convienience?

Comment: $x_i$ is not an arbitrary value but a probability (or relative frequency) that state $i$ is occupied, so must be in $[0,1]$ and is not multiple-dimension.  $\lim\limits_{x \to 0+} x \log(x) = 0$ so you can safely ignore points with zero probability.